# URL redirecting to a new page in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

A specific page in my web application has a URL `www.example.com/Test/Index`

However, I want to make this URL accessible when the user simply inputs `www.example.com/Test` instead of the whole thing.

So how can this be done using C# alone? Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Should we assume that this is in ASP.NET? Is it WebForms or MVC?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention this earlier, it is MVC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a redirect.  In ASP.NET this is Response.Redirect.  In MVC this is RedirectToAction("Index").  This will cause their browser to then request the other URL.

If you want the URL to not be changed/redirected, and show `www.example.com/Test`, then you can use a server side redirect.  ASP.NET: Server.Transfer.  In MVC you can just `return Index();` but this can be problematic sometimes.  A better option is to use a default route:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
  {
...
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

      routes.MapRoute(
          "Default", // Route name
          "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "Test", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
      );

    }
```

You should get this code automatically with any newly created MVC 3 application.  you just have to custimize it for the controller you want to respect this default route.

Comment: From where should this `RegisterRoutes` method be called? And what parameter should be passed?

Comment: You don't call it yourself, it will get called automatically, just because it is in the Global.asax.cs file(you should already have this file automatically).  So all you have to do is edit the RegisterRoutes method.  The MVC framework takes care of calling the method automatically when the application starts.